# Dynamic table creation with hspace

Tags: tables, spacing, expansion

I'm trying to create a dynamic table with a dynamic number of columns and `hspace` in it.

Here's what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{forloop}

\begin{document}
    \edef\rowdescriptor{|c|}
    \edef\pointsdescriptor{}
    \newcounter{tempcounter}
    \forloop{tempcounter}{0}{\value{tempcounter} < 5}{
        \edef\rowdescriptor{\rowdescriptor c|}
        \edef\pointsdescriptor{\expandafter\noexpand\pointsdescriptor & }
    }

    \expandafter\tabular\expandafter{\rowdescriptor}
    \hline
    \pointsdescriptor \\
    \hline
    \endtabular
\end{document}
```

This produces six boxes, as expected. But, I want to make the boxes wider, while keeping the `c`'s because the actual table has more rows with text that needs to be centered. For this, I'm using `\hspace`. So, when I change the second line inside the for-loop to

```
\edef\pointsdescriptor{\expandafter\noexpand\pointsdescriptor & \noexpand{\hspace{0.75cm}}}
```

I immediately get the error "Use of \forloop doesn't match its definition".

Am I somehow expanding the token wrong? What's the mistake here and how can I do better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `forloop` package seems to be very old...I recommend using `\foreach` from [pgffor](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf). For recursively building commands I always use `\gappto` from the [etoolbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package. Also, you don't need to build the `\rowdescriptor` macro because, instead, you can define:

```
\def\rowdescriptor{*5{|c}|}
```

The `*5{|c}` means "repeat the column specification `|c` 5 times".

Putting this together, the following does what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}
    \def\rowdescriptor{*5{|c}|}
    \foreach \x in {1,...,4}{
        \gappto\pointsdescriptor{\hspace*{0.75cm}&}
    }
    \xappto\pointsdescriptor{\noexpand\hspace*{0.75cm}}
    \expandafter\tabular\expandafter{\rowdescriptor}
    \hline
    \pointsdescriptor \\
    \hline
    \endtabular
\end{document}
```

I have also used `\hspace*` as this forces the space to be inserted. Note that it is necessary to add an "extra" `\hspace*` after the loop because there are 4 `&`s and 5 columns. Here's the output:

[image]

**EDIT**

Here is a version where the number of columns is hidden in a macro. Of course, you can use `\csname ....\endcsname` here but I prefer to use `\csuse{...}` from the [etoolbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)  package because I find this easier to read.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}
    \def\numberofcolumns{5}
    \def\pointsdescriptor{}% initialise
    \xdef\rowdescriptor{*{\csuse{numberofcolumns}}{|c}|}
    \foreach \x in {1,...,\numexpr\csuse{numberofcolumns}-1}{
        \gappto\pointsdescriptor{\hspace*{0.75cm}&}
    }
    \xappto\pointsdescriptor{\noexpand\hspace*{0.75cm}}
    \expandafter\tabular\expandafter{\rowdescriptor}
    \hline
    \pointsdescriptor \\
    \hline
    \endtabular
\end{document}
```

The output is the same as above. Note that there should be braces in `{\csuse{numberofcolumns}}` just in case there are more than 9 columns. Also, the `\xdef\rowdescriptor` is not strictly necessary above because the macro `numberofcolumns` is "static" but `\xdef` will be necessary if your actually csname depends on a counter, for example.

Here is a third variation where the code is put inside a macro that takes the number of columns as an optional argument, which defaults to 5:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand\mytabular[1][5]{%
    \bgroup%
    \def\rowdescriptor{*{#1}{|c}|}%
    \def\pointsdescriptor{}%
    \foreach \x in {1,...,\numexpr#1-1}{%
        \gappto\pointsdescriptor{\hspace*{0.75cm}&}
    }%
    \xappto\pointsdescriptor{\noexpand\hspace*{0.75cm}}%
    \expandafter\tabular\expandafter{\rowdescriptor}
    \hline
    \pointsdescriptor \\
    \hline
  \endtabular%
  \egroup%
}
\begin{document}
  \mytabular

  \mytabular[7]
\end{document}
```

This time the output is:

[image]

I am not sure what your real application is but I would probably try and use something like this approach.

Comment: Why `\xappto` instead of `\gappto` without the `\noexpand` (or just `\appto` if you don't need it to be global)?

Comment: @TH. You're right, `\gappto` would be better. I"ll edit. As `\foreach` operates inside a group it is necessary to use `\gappto` rather than`\appto`.

Comment: Thanks, this worked beautifully. However, I couldn't do the equivalent of `\def\rowdescriptor{*5{|c}|}` in my code because the `5` is actually `\csname somecommand\endcsname` and plugging that in didn't work as intended. Is there some special way to make it work with commands?

Comment: @HameerAbbasi I have edited my answer to allow for this using `\xdef` to expand `\csname...\endcsnme` -- actually, I use `\csuse`. In addition, I have used `\numexpr` in the construction of `\pointsdescriptor` so that it will also accept a variable number of columns

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for all the tips and expanding my (La)TeX knowledge quite a bit.

My application was actually generating a marks table for an exam's front page automatically from the number of points for each question. This was the last piece of the puzzle.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that `\expandafter\noexpand\pointsdescriptor` will work provided `\pointsdescriptor` has only one (first) token that need protection from expansion.  With e-TeX, this is easily covered using `\unexpanded`. You also need `{\noexpand\hspace{0.75cm}}` not `\noexpand{\hspace{0.75cm}}`, as the latter is applying `\noexpand` to `{`, which is already non-expandable. That would mean you'd get

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{forloop}

\begin{document}
    \edef\rowdescriptor{|c|}
    \edef\pointsdescriptor{}
    \newcounter{tempcounter}
    \forloop{tempcounter}{0}{\value{tempcounter} < 5}{
        \edef\rowdescriptor{\rowdescriptor c|}
        \edef\pointsdescriptor{\unexpanded\expandafter{\pointsdescriptor} & {\noexpand\hspace{0.75cm}}}
    }

    \expandafter\tabular\expandafter{\rowdescriptor}
    \hline
    \pointsdescriptor \\
    \hline
    \endtabular
\end{document}
```

Notably, this doesn't put in enough spaces: the [answer by Andrew](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/374708) already covers the way to solve that (and I think is a preferable way to go generally).